# Assigning grouped unique identifiers to a data frame

Tags: r

I've got a data frame like this:

```
library(dplyr)
topic <- c('topic1', 'topic2', 'topic3', 'topic4', 'topic5', 'topic6')
name <- c('name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name3')
data <- data.frame(topic, name)
```

No I would like to add a new column which assigns an identifier which is unique in regard to column *name*. The list of identifiers I get like this:

```
identifier <- ids::random_id(n_distinct(data$name), 3)
```

**But how can I assign the identifiers groupwise as my desired output illustrates?**

[image]

I'm using library dplyr as well as tidyr, so to rely on them in the answer is totally fine.

Comment: make a dataframe as dt <- data.frame(name  = unique(name), identifier = identifier) and then join the 2 tables. final_dt <- merge(data, dt, by = "name")

Comment: @Madamadam Just be aware that identifiers from `random_id()` may not be unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that for the solution below to work, you need dplyr>=1.10

```
mutate(data, identifier = ids::random_id(1,3), .by = name)

   topic  name identifier
1 topic1 name1     a1d197
2 topic2 name1     a1d197
3 topic3 name1     a1d197
4 topic4 name2     25c362
5 topic5 name3     edd84b
6 topic6 name3     edd84b
```

As the `ids::Random_id` does not necessarily generate unique identifiesr, why not just use `name` as the unique identifier?

Comment: Are the IDs guaranteed to be unique?

Comment: @RobertHacken You are right, they IDS arent guaranteed to be unique

Comment: Good objection! But for my use case, "almost" unique strings are sufficient. Sorry, using the term *identifier* wasn't quite correct.

Comment: @r2evans in  `ids::random` you can define the number of bytes. eg in this this case I defined them as 3. You can just use `ids::random_id(1)` which defaults to 16 bytes= 32 chars`

Comment: ahh, ... I don't have it, I see the utility of that, thanks @onyambu

Answer (score 1):

Can you use integers instead of strings? Given @RobertHacken's assertion that that function doesn't guarantee uniqueness, you can always sequence along the unique values.

```r
data$id <- match(data$name, unique(data$name))
data
#    topic  name id
# 1 topic1 name1  1
# 2 topic2 name1  1
# 3 topic3 name1  1
# 4 topic4 name2  2
# 5 topic5 name3  3
# 6 topic6 name3  3
```

Comment: Good solution, simple and unique. But I need a value that isn't deterministic and has the quality of an almost random string.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to use a hashing function, because it will always create the same hash when it encounters the same name (provided you have safeguards against entering spaces and random dots and dashes and such) and it vectorizes nicely

```
require(openssl)
topic <- c('topic1', 'topic2', 'topic3', 'topic4', 'topic5', 'topic6')
name <- c('name1', 'name1', 'name1', 'name2', 'name3', 'name3')
data <- data.frame(topic, name)

 

data$ids<-md5(data$name)
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution as well, but I need a value that isn't deterministic and has the quality of an almost random string.